# Logging in ASP.NET application runnin in Docker container

Tags: logging, docker

Lately got interested in Docker approach - running asp.net application in Docker container deployed on Linux.

How would looging system looks like with this approach? What libs to use? Where logs actually written? log4net? How can i reach to read these logs written?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of what logging framework to use. Docker is just providing you a setup for running your applications. You can mount a volume from your host machine and save the logs to a file that will be located in that volume. Then you can **easily access the logs even after the container is dead.**

Comment: Well, a question was, how can I setup logging mechanism to write logs on to text file inside a container. Or should it be writing into container`s host machine? how? How can I specify a route to write somethin out of the container?

Comment: You would specify the route in the same manner as you would on your local machine. There would be no difference in that. I don't know the exact syntax for your logging mechanism but the text file should lie in the directory you want to mount in the docker container. There is no difference as such in specifying something out of container. It is just another machine for the user.